# Open multiple firefox instances with different profiles on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, profile, instances

What is the best way to open different firefox instances (firefox 3 to 10) with different profiles (on 10.5, 10.6 and 10.7)?

With versions prior to Firefox-7, modifying the content of the firefox package and adding -no-remote -P {PROFILE} worked.

However, with the latest versions of firefox it's not working.

I've also tried with Automator without success.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and fixed it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to do this using clickable icons, or is command-line OK?

Comment: You _might_ be able to use Automator to run things like "/path/to/Firefox-7.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -no-remote -P prifilename".  Or did you try that already?  I'm not sure how you tried to use Automator so far...

Comment: I've tried automator with a profile for every firefox instance, without luck.

Comment: This question belongs on [Ask Different, and has been asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384745/how-can-i-start-firefox-with-a-different-profile-on-a-mac) there.

Answer (score 3):

For new versions of Firefox use the following command:

/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P -no-remote &> /dev/null &

source: http://sonnygill.net/mac/mac-multiple-firefox-profiles/

On page explains how to use Automator to create a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

@dalvan answer does not work any more (10.15)

Workaround I've found is:

- run first firefox instance as normal (profile chooser window opens, select `primary` profile)
- use an `Automator.app` or run from shell `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -P &` and choose `secondary` profile

All links transfered from other applications will be opened in `primary` profile

Ref. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1653218

**UPDATE (2024-01-01)**

Starting from the shell (or `Automator` app) has stopped working for me for some reason, but there is another workaround

```
$ open -n /Applications/Firefox.app --args -P
```

Answer (score 0):

This did work for me for several FF/Beta/Aurora version 10+

http://xulforge.com/blog/2011/07/multiple-firefox-instances-mac/

+ https://superuser.com/questions/37811/how-can-i-change-an-application-icon-in-mac-os-x for the icons ;)